# LSTM Temperature prediction example from Deep Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying out the example from the following link,

https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.ipynb

In step 36, where dropout and recurrent dropout is being used, the loss show NaN when I try to train the model.

Can somebody please explain why this is happening, and also guide me to a solution.

The code related to the issue is here:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(32,
                     dropout=0.1,
                     recurrent_dropout=0.5,
                     return_sequences=True,
                     input_shape=(None, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.GRU(64, activation='relu',
                     dropout=0.1, 
                     recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                              steps_per_epoch=500,
                              epochs=40,
                              validation_data=val_gen,
                              validation_steps=val_steps)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(32,
                     dropout=0.1,
                     recurrent_dropout=0.5,
                     return_sequences=True,
                     input_shape=(None, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.GRU(64, activation='relu',
                     dropout=0.1, 
                     recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                              steps_per_epoch=500,
                              epochs=40,
                              validation_data=val_gen,
                              validation_steps=val_steps)
```

This is the step that's causing the issue.

Also when I remove the recurrent dropout, it works fine.